# google fire run @property automatically

Tags: python, python-fire

I use [google fire](https://github.com/google/python-fire) for cli, and met an issue below.

```py
# test.py
import fire

class C:
    @property
    def foo(self):
        print('foo')

    def bar(self):
        print('bar')

fire.Fire()
```

then run as

```
python test.py C bar

foo
bar
```

as seen it print "foo" which is unwanted, any elegant way to solve this?

Comment: I can't replicate the issue on Python 3.6.5/macOS

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by updating the `fire` version to 3.x.